# What lighting setup is recommended to achieve a purple atmosphere in an indoor hall

Tags: lighting

The video is taking place in a night.
I want the beginning of the hall to be purple lighted and a fade to black, at the end of the hall.

[image: Location]

The Left photo, is the location when regular lights are on, and the Right one, is the what I want to achieve.

Is it enough to use a 800w - or 1000w - light on the ceiling with color filters to achieve this atmosphere?

Comment: Your solution sounds like it would work great. If it's possible, do a camera test beforehand, and if there will be people in your scene include some people in the test. You might also do some post-production tweaking to get the intensity or look you want.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest issue with having only one powerful light source for the whole hall might be the foreground being too bright and the fall-off to dark being to fast. You may compensate for this by placing the light way behind the camera, if this doesn't cast any camera/crew shadows inside the frame. This setup will give you a much smoother fall-off, but will also make the scene darker.

The scientific reason is the 'inverse square law' described here: http://www.usefulphototips.com/2012/04/10/controlling-light-falloff/

But I have another suggestion: Why don't you keep the lighting as shown on the left, and just turn some lights off at the far end of the hall. For achieving the pink effect you then use a color gel in front of the lens. And for having some more colors than just pink in the frame, you can add one or two red light sources distributed in the hall.